# Can a morphism be a binary operation in category theory? (Fourier transform example)

Tags: category-theory, fourier-analysis

I want to express a simple idea that Fourier transform $F(a)$ of a vector $a$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ sets a correspondence between the operations of convolution of vectors in time domain and Hadamard product of their Fourier images in frequency domain.

A binary operation of convolution: $\circledast: \mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ over vectors $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ produces a vector $c$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. A binary operation of Hadamard product $\odot: \mathbb{C}^n, \mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^n$ over vectors $F(a)$ and $F(b)$ produces a vector $F(c)$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Application of Fourier transform to vector $c = a \circledast b$ is equivalent to application of Hadamard product operation to Fourier images of vectors $a$ and $b$:

$F(c) = F(a) \odot F(b) = F(a \circledast b)$

I'm not quite used to the language of category theory, but it feels like a right language to express this relation. Fourier transform seems to be a functor, and convolution and Hadamard products would've been morphisms in their respective categories, but the problem is that from the definition it seems that a morphism is a unary operation, while convolution and Hadamard product are binary. Is that so?

Comment: The binary operations would be the *composition* in the categories which are actually rather monoids or semigroups.